# Kohana 3.2 Upload Exception

Tags: kohana

I'm using Kohana 3.2.
I have a category form with two upload fields: one is image, and one is banner. In my controller i got:

```
try{

    $model_category->save();

}catch(ORM_Validation_Exception $e){
    $errors = $e->errors('forms');

    //echo Debug::vars($errors);
}catch (Exception $e){
    $upload_errors = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Rules for my images in the model:

```
'photo' => array(

                    array('Upload::valid'),
                    array('Upload::type', array(array(':value'),array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'))),
                    array('Upload::size', array(array(':value'), array('500000')))
                ),

                'banner' => array(
                        //array(array($this, 'validate_photo'), array(':validation', ':field', ':value', 500, 100)),
                        array('Upload::valid'),
                        array('Upload::type', array(array(':value'),array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'))),
                        array('Upload::size', array(array(':value'), array('5000000')))
                ),
```

I got into such problem: if i leave a required field, for example "name" and upload an txt file to force both exceptions occur, it can only catch the ORM_Validation_Exception. So my question is how to merge the two error array. And very important, how can i know if it's an exeception for the image field or the banner field.

I have been trying over for days but end up with nothing. Please help me out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Validation` class to validate your uploads and then if validation is ok - save the model.

Something like:

```
    $validate_image = Validation::factory($_FILES);

    $validate_image->rule($name, 'Upload::valid');
    $validate_image->rule($name, 'Upload::type', array($_FILES['image'], array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif')));
    $validate_image->rule($name, 'Upload::size', array($_FILES[$name], '500000'));


    $validate_banner = Validation::factory($_FILES);

    $validate_banner->rule($name, 'Upload::valid');
    $validate_banner->rule($name, 'Upload::type', array($_FILES[$name], array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif')));
    $validate_banner->rule($name, 'Upload::size', array($_FILES[$name], '500000'));

    if ($validate_image->check() && $validate_banner->check()) {

        $model_category->save();

    }
```